# Json conversion from one form to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to convert this JSON to the format mentioned in the result section.

```
[
  { name: "FieldData[FirstName][Operator]", value: "=" }
  { name: "FieldData[FirstName][Value]", value: "test" }
  { name: "FieldData[LastName][Operator]", value: "=" }
  { name: "FieldData[LastName][Value]", value: "test" }
]
```

Result:

```
FieldData
{
    FirstName {
        Operator: =,
        Value: tset
    },
    LastName {
        Operator: =,
        Value: tset
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw you are missing `,` after each `}` in your array `[]`

Comment: Stackoverflow works best when you ask narrowly focused questions. Asking people to write a complete data format converter is really too broad. (It also helps when you don't ask about JSON and then provide data which isn't valid JSON)

Comment: Correction Okay. But I need solution with that. If you are able to provide solution  then tell me

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.prototype.split` function and regex, you can extract the strings inside `[]` and based on that data, you can generate the nested objects as follows.

```js
const input = [
  {name: "FieldData[FirstName][Operator]", value: "="},
  {name: "FieldData[FirstName][Value]", value: "test"},
  {name: "FieldData[LastName][Operator]", value: "="},
  {name: "FieldData[LastName][Value]", value: "test"}
];

const result = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const keys = cur.name.split(/\[(.*?)\]/).filter((item) => item);
  let item = acc;
  for (let index = 0; index < keys.length - 1; index ++) {
    const key = keys[index];
    if (!(key in item)) {
      item[key] = {};
    }
    item = item[key];
  }
  item[keys[keys.length - 1]] = cur.value;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If there exists inbuit function to do this then please provide solution with that

Comment: What do you need exactly? the callback inside `reduce` is the part to make the nested objects. and in `reduce` callback, `item` variable is reference variable of `acc`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex and javascript's ability to set properties using `obj[propname] = value` as the same as `obj.propname = value`

```js
var d = [
  { name: "FieldData[FirstName][Operator]", value: "=" },
  { name: "FieldData[FirstName][Value]", value: "test" },
  { name: "FieldData[LastName][Operator]", value: "=" },
  { name: "FieldData[LastName][Value]", value: "test" },
];

var r = {};
for (var i=0; i<d.length; ++i)
{
    var parts = d[i].name.match(/(.*)\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]/) 
    
    r[parts[1]] = r[parts[1]] || {};
    r[parts[1]][parts[2]] = r[parts[1]][parts[2]] || {};
    r[parts[1]][parts[2]][parts[3]] = d[i].value;
}
console.log(r)
```

(note: SO console JSONifies the object, look in the browser console for the object)